# How to see, if a foreign key is enforced?

Tags: db2, foreign-key

How can I see in IBM DB2, if a foreign key is in enforced Status?
In the systemviews REF_CONSTRAINTS and REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS I see them, but I cannot see, if they are in enforced Status. Is there another System view, where I can see that?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what version of db2 you are using, but if it's LUW you can use [SYSCAT.TABCONST](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001062.html) (see column ENFORCED):

```
select enforced 
from syscat.tabconst 
where tabschema = ?
  and tabname = ?
  and constname = ?
```

FWIW, it is better to use the syscat views (vs sysibm), since they are more stable between versions.

Comment: If DB2 for IBM i, look in `qsys2.syscst`